# How do I make items selectable in an NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` that is bound to an `NSTreeController`. When I click on a row in the `NSOutlineView`, nothing happens, that is, it is not selected.  However, when I insert an object using add: in the tree controller, the inserted item is highlighted.  I think the problem with the rows not being selectable has to do with the bindings but I can't find the problem.  The have the `NSOutlineView's 'Selection Index Paths'` bound to the tree controller's `selectionIndexPaths` 'Controller Key'.  Are there any other bindings that need to be configured?  Do I need to have the Sort Description binding?

The NSOutlineView is actually a custom subclass, so I made the subclass its own delegate and implemented one of the delegate methods to see if they're being called:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldSelectItem:(id)item {
    return YES;
}
```

A breakpoint on `return YES` shows me that the method is never called.

Comment: Nope.  I updated the question with more details.

Comment: What about `outlineViewSelectionDidChange:`?

Comment: `outlineViewSelectionDidChange:` is not called when I click on the view but it is called when I insert an object in the controller.

Comment: Interesting.  And what is this outlineview contained in?  Borderless windows and NSPanels often don't disseminate click events correctly.

Comment: Have you checked your bindings? E.g. setting `-NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1` in your launch arguments (see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html))?

Comment: Yup, I had a misconfigured Double Click Argument binding. Interestingly, setting -NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1 didn't reveal the problem.